# Hide/show a part of text using only Javascript (jQuery) and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` which contains long text. I'd like to make sure that after loading the page my div will show first few words and after click on it, it will expand and show whole long text. How can I make it in Javascript or jQuery and CSS? I know names of classes, id etc. but I don't have access to html file so I can't write additional code inside html file.

Thank you for help!

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please show the code

Comment: Is your script included on the page? If not, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

#### Expand `div` via CSS [`overflow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

One way of doing this is to write css where you set a `height` on your `div` and set the `overflow` to `hidden`.

After a `click` on the `div`, the `overflow` can be set to `visible`:

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non felis eu massa dictum rutrum ac et massa. Morbi ante ante, faucibus non varius ut, sollicitudin blandit libero. Nam magna elit, molestie et nulla in, aliquam sagittis enim. Donec eget nulla
  hendrerit, molestie dui at, ultrices sapien...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").click(function() {
    $(this).css("overflow", "visible");
  });
});
```

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRxYNo)**

---

#### Expand and hide `div` via CSS [`overflow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) and JQuery's [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

If you want to show and hide the text when clicking on the `div`, you can use the same css `overflow` strategy and toggle the class in JQuery like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non felis eu massa dictum rutrum ac et massa. Morbi ante ante, faucibus non varius ut, sollicitudin blandit libero. Nam magna elit, molestie et nulla in, aliquam sagittis enim. Donec eget nulla
  hendrerit, molestie dui at, ultrices sapien...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expand {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
  });
});
```

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/yXmYbx)**

---

#### Animate in a child `div` via JQuery's [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)

If you want to animate it, you can show and hide the text you want to expand. I used a `div` for the additional expanded text so it is forced onto the next line (this is more responsive friendly):

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non felis eu massa 
  dictum rutrum ac et massa. Morbi ante ante, faucibus non varius ut, sollicitudin blandit libero.  
  <div id='more'>
    Nam magna elit, molestie et nulla in, aliquam sagittis enim. Donec eget nulla hendrerit, 
    molestie dui at, ultrices sapien. In iaculis nunc sapien, sit amet iaculis velit viverra in. Proin in massa magna. Nullam volutpat...
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#more {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").click(function() {
    if ($("#more").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#more").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
      $("#more").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/QgejoZ)**

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css({"overflow":"auto", "white-space":"normal"});
})
```

```css
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed leo urna. Fusce varius turpis non elit interdum, quis consectetur neque sollicitudin. Suspendisse ipsum mauris, posuere quis est ac, hendrerit iaculis mauris. In ultrices volutpat rhoncus. Suspendisse semper velit libero, ut consequat erat elementum non. Nullam eu imperdiet quam. Quisque ullamcorper molestie vehicula. Praesent non tellus cursus, cursus urna a, feugiat justo. Sed sit amet efficitur quam. Morbi enim urna, varius eget sodales quis, gravida eu lacus. Donec dignissim dapibus cursus. Donec vulputate lacus purus, porttitor tincidunt velit eleifend ac. Praesent vestibulum lectus quis maximus gravida. Donec et lorem eu arcu volutpat maximus. Proin nulla nibh, blandit a hendrerit at, condimentum vel libero.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 Divs, one with the first part, then when click on div show another div with all content and hide the first div.

```
<div onclick="showall();" id="somecontent">Some words</div>
<div id="fullcontent" style="display: none;">All content</div>

<script>
   function showall(){
      $('#fullcontent').show();
      $('#somecontent').hide();
   }
</script>
```

what do you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a fiddle for you. Not sure if this is exactly what you want.

You can create a `span` inside a `div` and set its `display:none`. Then from jQuery `click` you can again change the display to `inline`.

Here's the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/gw164g4x/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div").click(function(){
    $("span.clickshow").css("display","inline");
  })
});
```

```css
.clickshow{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
<span class="clickshow">adipisicing elit. Nulla sapiente natus nesciunt, nostrum. Cum excepturi, assumenda laboriosam voluptatibus quia, aut aspernatur. Dolorem qui obcaecati tenetur repudiandae minus libero ea ratione.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Simple Way,

```js
document.getElementById("content").onclick = function() {
  this.style.height = 'auto';
}
```

```css
#content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<b>This is a Heading</b>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this the one you need , ignore if you not like the post

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";
    

    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
     display: none;
 }
 .morelink {
     display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more">
      Morbi placerat imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var longtext = "Lorem ipsum dolor ljghlkjghdfghjd lkfhglkdgjlskgj;ljglksjg sldjlsdjlgsdj;lsdj g;lsdkjglsjgl;sdj; ldkjlsd;jgs";
var smalltext = "Lorem ipsum dolor";
$(function() {
    $("#mydiv").text(smalltext);
    var done = false;
    $("#mydiv").click(function() {
        if (!done) {
            done = true;
            $(this).text(longtext);
        }
    });
});
```